# @Transactional saveAll not working for a table in 2nd data source Spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 data sources, ds1, ds2. In a single service which is @Transactional I have to get the values from two tables and update them.

Sample snippet

```
    @Service
    public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    ds1Repository ds1Repository; // from data source 1 (DB Name - DB1) MYSQL
    @Autowired
    ds2Repository ds2Repository; // from data source 2 (DB Name - DB2) MYSQL

    @Transactional (javax.Transactional)
    public void processUpdates() {
        // Able to get the result set from both the data sources
        List<Data1> ds1Data = ds1Repository.findAll();
        List<Data2> ds2Data = ds1Repository.findAll();

        // modified the collections ds1Data & ds2Data

        // This is getting updated
        ds1Repository.saveAll(ds1Data);

        // This update is not heppening and no exception thrown
        ds2Repository.saveAll(ds2Data);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following wys:

1. I have configired both the data sources which are working fine, able to read the data from boths databases
2. After searching, tried ChainedTransactionManager, by defining custom transaction manager names for both data sources and used @Transactional(value="chainedTransactionManager") on top of service. Still did not work.

Can anyone help me what was wring with the code ? why the data only on data source 2 is not getting persisted?

Comment: Can you paste your attempt with `ChainedTransactionManager`?

Comment: `public class MultiDataSourceTransactionManager {
    @Bean(name = "chainedTransactionManager")
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager ds1,
                                                        @Qualifier("tm2") PlatformTransactionManager ds2) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(ds1, ds2);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

- You have 2 Datasources, which means you will have 2
  TransactionManager beans
- Now, when you use @Transactional without specifying the name, it will
  work with default TransactionManager
- Which means, only the default transaction gets committed once
  processUpdate() completes

Suggestion

- I don't know if you have requirement for distributed transaction management, if not, then just use independent @Transactional on saveAll() with appropriate TransactionManager name

Answer (score 0):

As Arjun suggested you could use the transactional on the saveAll with the appropriate transaction Manager.

Or you could define a distributed Transaction Manager like so (Assuming you have beans for both transaction Managers):

```
@Configuration
public class ChainedTransactionManagerConfig
{
    /**
     * combined TM
     */
    public static final String TRANSACTION_MANAGER = "chainedTransactionManager";

    /**
     * 
     * @param oneTransactionManager oneTransactionManager
     * @param twoTransactionManager twoTransactionManager
     * @return combined TM
     */
    @Bean(name = TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager(
            // Bean name of the first one
            @Qualifier("firstTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager oneTransactionManager,
            // Bean name of the second one
            @Qualifier("secondTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager twoTransactionManager)
    {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(oneTransactionManager, twoTransactionManager);
    }
}
```

then you could use it on your Method like so:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(transactionManager = ChainedTransactionManagerConfig.TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
```

Also please use the transactional Annotation from Spring (org.springframework.transaction.annotation)